# Unable to set the Visible property of the PivotItem class when setting PivotItem.Visible = false

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I want to make `PivotItem.Visible = False` but I keep getting an error:

> Unable to set the Visible property of the PivotItem class

I tried all the solutions I found in the internet but none seems to work

```
Sub FloorCompareSetter()

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Dim PivotSheet As Worksheet

    Set PivotSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PIVOT")
    PivotSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").RefreshTable

    Set pt = PivotSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5")
    pt.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone

    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Period")

    For Each pi In _
        pt.PivotFields("Period").PivotItems
        Select Case pi.Name
            Case Is = "1601A"
                pi.Visible = True
            Case Else
                pi.Visible = False 'error
        End Select
    Next pi

End Sub
```

I tried refreshing the table and this line but still not working:

> pt.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone

Here is a picture of my pivot table:

[image]

What am i doing wrong and how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I included it in the question- `Unable to set the Visible property of the PivotItem class`

Answer (score 7):

You will get this error if you attempt to hide all the items on any axis (rows, columns, filters). You can trap this error in your code by comparing the `HiddenItems.Count` property of your `PivotField` object to the `PivotItems.Count` property of the same object and make sure you are not trying to remove the last item of the collection from view:

So in your case statement, you can replace with update with something like:

```
Select Case pi.Name
    Case Is = "1601A"
        pi.Visible = True
    Case Else
        If pf.HiddenItems.Count < (pf.PivotItems.Count - 1) Then
            pi.Visible = False 
        Else
            MsgBox "Cannot hide all the items on this axis"
            Exit For '<~~ break the loop to stop the MsgBox popping up
        End If
End Select
```

Note that whilst manipulating the pivot table Excel won't allow you to remove the last item from an axis - the OK button will become disabled:

[image]

Comment: this keeps always bringing this message box !

Comment: I updated the code to break the loop when it hits the point where it can't set any more items to hidden.

Comment: using this can will break the code before it gets and show me the column I want

Comment: In your example picture that you posted is `1601A` in the column axis? The error is caused because if `1601A` is not present then you will try and hide *all* the items on that axis.

Comment: yes its there, if its not there, it won't even pass the 
Case Is = "1601A"

Answer (score 0):

I added

> On Error Resume Next

before

> pi.Visible = False 'error

it works now !

Answer (score 0):

The issue of the above solutions are: Before the loop reach the expected filter value, Robin's solution will stop (suppose the ideal value is the last item, but an unwanted value is the 1st one, and being the only one selected), while Sabir's solution (On Error Resume Next) can leave an unwanted value being selected.

How about before the loop starts, set the last item as visible? Like:

```
maxFilterIndex = objPivotField.PivotItems.Count
objPivotField.PivotItems(maxFilterIndex).Visible = True
```

Then at the end of the loop, if the expected value is not in the filter at all, we can leave the last one as visible, but pop a message box saying the value is not found.

```
With objPivotField

maxFilterIndex = objPivotField.PivotItems.Count
objPivotField.PivotItems(maxFilterIndex).Visible = True

For i = 1 To maxFilterIndex

    If objPivotField.PivotItems(i).Name = filterValue Then
        objPivotField.PivotItems(i).Visible = True
    Else
        'This is to skip the error. But the prob is it will leave the last quarter visible, if the last elelment not being ticked.
        On Error Resume Next
        objPivotField.PivotItems(i).Visible = False
        
        If i = maxFilterIndex _
           And objPivotField.HiddenItems.Count = (maxFilterIndex - 1) Then
            MsgBox "The chosen filter values are not found, and EXCEL can't hide all the items on this Pivot filter"               
        End If
    End If
Next i
End With
```